# Blockly enter text and obtain numbers

Tags: xml, blockly, google-blockly

I need to create in blockly the following example: I need to introduce a number with letters (for example four thousand three hundred twenty seven) and blockly should display the number with numbers. The max length can be 999.999.999 with 2 decimals. I don’t know how to set it. Can someone help me?

I don’t have any experience at coding